# Compare two columns, if a value is missing in one of them add to it[Excel]

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, addition

I have two columns of two different tables that I want to compare (same worksheet)
I have column "A" [which belongs to a master table] where I have Owners names for different projects.
Then I have column "D" [which belongs to a table that shows the number of project each owner has]

What I want to do is that every time I write new projects with their respective Owners in the first table, if the owner is not on the second table, Column "D", that the new name is added automatically to to this column "D".

Is that possible?

Edit:

Hi thank you for your replies 
Here is a graphic example. 
[Table1&2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAS0f.jpg)
Table 1 (All tasks with their owner, manually entered)

```
    <table><tr>
   <th>Owner</th>
    <th>Task</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Task1</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<td>Mary</td>
    <td>Task2</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<td>Patrick</td>
    <td>Task3</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
  <td>Task</td></tr></table>
```

Table 2 (all the Owners)

```
   <table><tr>
   <th>Owner</th>
    <th>Overdue Tasks</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
<td>Patrick</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
</table>
```

So what I want is if I add new tasks in table 1 and they have an owner that is not yet in table 2, that the name of this new Owner is automatically updated in the table 2.

What If tried so far was to add a new column with =NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(H2,$P$2:$P$46,0)))
to check if the name is in table 2
and then tried with =IF($L2="TRUE",SUM($H2)," ") in the second table.
But I think thats a paradox and won't work

Also tried =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H2,$P2:$P145,COLUMN(H2),FALSE),"")
But doesn't work either

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is possible to do it but... there should be a minimum content in one question: Input sample (if needed), expected output sample (is needed), what you try, what you research... What did you try? Could you upload a sample? (input and expected output)

Comment: What part of the code you have written gives you a problem? Please post your code and describe the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I just edited it with some detail :)

Comment: In the first paragraph you'd mentioned column A & D.. but in the formula there is column H & P. How does these two relates?